# Accessing python dictionary whose keys are tuples with a wildcard

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with tuples as keys:

```
d = {
    ('John', 'Blue', 1): 100,
    ('Bill', 'Green', 5): 200,
    ('Paul', 'Blue', 4): 300,
    ('Bill', 'Green', 7): 400
}
```

Is it possible to pull out the values of those keys which match, say `('Bill', 'Green', _)`, such that the output will be `[200, 400]`?

Comment: what's wrong with simply a for-loop?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a simple for-loop. I was wondering if there was a smart way to pull the values, such as a `d[('Bill', 'Green', _)]`, but that doesn't work. As the answers suggest, I guess the only way about it is to use a for-loop or a list comprehension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't expect it to be very fast, but:

```
search_key = ("Paul", "Blue")
values = [value for key, value in d.items() if search_key == key[:len(search_key)]]
```

Will return all matching values.

EDIT: by replacing `key[:2]` with `key[:len(search_key)]` this solution also works with keys with only one value, eg `("Bill",)` will return all values with keys starting with "Bill".

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension:

```
[d[k] for k in d.keys() if k[0]=='Bill' and k[1]=='Green']
Out[37]: [400, 200]
```

Answer (score 0):

A python dictionary is implemented as a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) so there is no efficient way to find similar keys, only exact matches. You can of course loop over the items and check each key to see if it matches your pattern.

Python does have a `groupby` function which might be helpful if you're looking for multiple matches, for example:

```
from itertools import groupby

d = {
    ('John', 'Blue', 1): 100,
    ('Bill', 'Green', 5): 200,
    ('Paul', 'Blue', 4): 300,
    ('Bill', 'Green', 7): 400
}

keyfunc = lambda (key, value): (key[0], key[1])
g = sorted(d.items(), key=keyfunc)
g = groupby(g, key=keyfunc)

for (partial_key, value) in g:
    print partial_key, len(list(value))
# ('Bill', 'Green') 2
# ('John', 'Blue') 1
# ('Paul', 'Blue') 1
```

Answer (score 0):

a variant of the path followed by MaThMaX

```
[d[(a,b,c)] for a, b, c in d.keys() if a == 'Bill' and b == 'Green']
```